# PHP strtok reset?

Tags: php, strtok

I've not used `strtok` before, the PHP manual doesn't give a very good explanation.

I want to loop through the tokenized string more than once. How do I reset it back to the beginning?

Comment: Really, -1 points for this question. I've been a member here for about 2 weeks and I get the impression that most of the members here are very elitist. The answer to this question is not obvious to someone who has not used the function before, it is not explained well in the PHP documentation. Do you guys really expect everyone to know the answers to the questions magically? Is the point of the site not for asking questions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just call again `strtok` with two params and that is:

```
$tok = strtok($string, $tokens);
```

From the [strtok official doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtok.php):

> To start over, or to tokenize a new string you simply call strtok with
>   the string argument again to initialize it.

Comment: I was afraid that would be the answer, I was hoping to not have to store the string separately.

Answer (score 2):

As the documentation says:

> Note that only the first call to strtok uses the string argument.
>   Every subsequent call to strtok only needs the token to use, as it
>   keeps track of where it is in the current string. **To start over, or to
>   tokenize a new string you simply call strtok with the string argument
>   again to initialize it.** Note that you may put multiple tokens in the
>   token parameter. The string will be tokenized when any one of the
>   characters in the argument are found.

Answer (score 2):

You have to call again `strtok()` as the others said.

Here's a function which simply returns an array for you:

```
function tokenize($delimiter, $str)
{
  $tokens = array();
  $tok = strtok($str, $delimiter);

  do
  {
    $tokens[] = $tok;    

    $tok = strtok($delimiter);
  }
  while ($tok !== false);

  return $tokens;
}
```

On codepad.org: http://codepad.org/2ySQ51TC